# VsCode-"Run Python File in Terminal" disappears each time I open a Python File

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have already installed the python extension.But there is no "Run Python File in Terminal" option in the right-click menu each time I open a python file. The "Run Python File in Terminal" option only appears when I open the python extension
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHOrD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us9CN.png)

Comment: My guess is your installation of the extension is corrupted. Otherwise just make sure you have waited long enough for the extension to have fully loaded.

Comment: Are you using Jupyter?  This happens to me if I'm using Jupyter.

Comment: Ignore my earlier comment. "Run python file in terminal" shows up for all my files. Sorry.

Comment: I have waited for a very long time, and I have even reinstalled the extension several times, but those didn't work.